Is it possible to export 3d models from an editor like blender to 2d sprite stackable files?
Basically, I am trying to figure out if I can make a 3d model in blender but then export it into like a .zip with tons of files of a top-down view that if you stacked them in a 2d editor, you would see your 3d model.
I need it to be like what spritestack.io does but not pixel art, 3d models.
I tried looking places but nowhere else really talks about this.
